# ¿Cómo manejar esta situación relacional en Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

Tengo tres relaciones de muchos a muchos en una forma circular.

[image: Database design]

1. Un plato puede tener muchos productos y un producto puede ser añadido a muchos platos.
2. Además un plato puede estar compuesto por producto manufacturados y un producto manufacturado puede ser añadido a varios platos.
3. Ahora el problema real es que a su ves un producto manufacturado puede estar compuesto por muchos productos y un producto puede estar en varios productos manufacturados.

Lo que necesito es un ejemplo del diseño de modelos y del DbContext para manejar esta situación.

Aquí les muestro lo que tengo programado ahora:

La clase plato:

```
namespace Sistema_Restaurant_DataLayer.Models        
{        
    public class Plato        
    {        
        [Key]        
        public int PlatoId { get; set; }        
        [Required]        
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]        
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 5)]        
        public string Nombre { get; set; }        
        [Required]        
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]        
        [Range(0, 9999.99)]        
        public decimal Precio { get; set; } = 0;        
        public List<VentasPlato> Ventas { get; set; } = new List<VentasPlato>();        
        public List<PlatoProducto> PlatoProducto { get; set; } = new List<PlatoProducto>();        
        public List<PlatoProductoElaborado> PlatoProductoElaborado { get; set; } = new List<PlatoProductoElaborado>();        
    }        
}
```

La clase Producto:

```
namespace Sistema_Restaurant_DataLayer.Models        
{        
    public class Producto        
    {         
        [Key]        
        public int ProductoId { get; set; }        
        [Required]        
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]        
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 5)]        
        public string Nombre { get; set; } = "";        
        [Required]        
        public int UnidadID { get; set; }        
        [Required]         
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]        
        [Range(0, 99999.99)]        
        public decimal Existencia { get; set; } = 0;        
        public bool EsAgrego { get; set; } = false;        
        public List<PlatoProducto> PlatoProducto { get; set; } = new List<PlatoProducto>();        
        public List<ProductoElaboradoProducto> ProductoElaboradoProducto { get; set; } = new List<ProductoElaboradoProducto>();         

    }       
}
```

La clase Producto Elaborado:

```
namespace Sistema_Restaurant_DataLayer.Models        
{        
    public class ProductoElaborado        
    {        
        [Key]        
        public int ProductoElaboradoId { get; set; }        
        [Required]        
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]                
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength =5)]               
        public string Nombre { get; set; } = "";        
        [Required]        
        public int UnidadID { get; set; }        
        [Required]         
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]         
        [Range(0, 99999.99)]        
        public decimal Existencia { get; set; } = 0;        
        public bool EsAgrego { get; set; } = false;         
        public List<PlatoProductoElaborado> PlatoProductoElaborado { get; set; } = new List<PlatoProductoElaborado>();          
        public List<ProductoElaboradoProducto> ProductoElaboradoProducto { get; set; } = new List<ProductoElaboradoProducto>();         
    }         
}
```

La clase PlatoProduto

```
namespace Sistema_Restaurant_DataLayer.Models       
{        
    public class PlatoProducto        
    {        
        [Required]        
        public int PlatoId { get; set; }        
        [Required]        
        public int ProductoId { get; set; }        
        [Required]        
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]         
        [Range(0, 999.99)]        
        public decimal GastoProducto { get; set; } = 0;        
        [ForeignKey("PlatoId")]        
        public Plato Plato { get; set; }        
        [ForeignKey("ProductoId")]        
        public Producto Producto { get; set; }        

    }        
}
```

La clase PLatoProductoElaborado

```
namespace Sistema_Restaurant_DataLayer.Models
{
    public class PlatoProductoElaborado       
    {        
        [Required]        
        public int PlatoId { get; set; }        
        [Required]         
        public int ProductoElaboradoId { get; set; }        
        [Required]        
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]         
        [Range(0, 999.99)]        
        public decimal GastoProductoElaborado { get; set; } = 0;        
        [ForeignKey("PlatoId")]         
        public Plato Plato { get; set; }         
        [ForeignKey("ProductoElaboradoId")]         
        public ProductoElaborado ProductoElaborado { get; set; }         
    }         
}
```

La clase ProductoElaboradoProducto

```
namespace Sistema_Restaurant_DataLayer.Models       
{        
    public class ProductoElaboradoProducto        
    {        
        [Required]        
        public int ProductoId { get; set; }         
        [Required]          
        public int ProductoElaboradoId { get; set; }           
        [Required]           
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]           
        [Range(0, 999.99)]          
        public decimal GastoProducto { get; set; } = 0;          
        [ForeignKey("ProductoId")]           
        public Producto Producto { get; set; }          
        [ForeignKey("ProductoElaboradoId")]           
        public ProductoElaborado ProductoElaborado { get; set; }           
    }            
}
```

Mi BDContext

```
public class RestaurantAppContext : DbContext        
    {        
        public RestaurantAppContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }         

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)         
        {          
            modelBuilder.Entity<PlatoProducto>().HasKey(x => new { x.PlatoId, x.ProductoId });          
            modelBuilder.Entity<PlatoProductoElaborado>().HasKey(x => new { x.PlatoId, x.ProductoElaboradoId });        
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductoElaboradoProducto>().HasKey(x => new { x.ProductoId, x.ProductoElaboradoId });         

            modelBuilder.Entity<PlatoProducto>()         
                .HasOne<Plato>(e => e.Plato)         
                .WithMany(d => d.PlatoProducto)                        
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);        

            modelBuilder.Entity<PlatoProducto>()         
                .HasOne<Producto>(e => e.Producto)        
                .WithMany(d => d.PlatoProducto)         
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);         

            modelBuilder.Entity<PlatoProductoElaborado>()         
                .HasOne<Plato>(e => e.Plato)         
                .WithMany(d => d.PlatoProductoElaborado)         
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);         

            modelBuilder.Entity<PlatoProductoElaborado>()          
                .HasOne<ProductoElaborado>(e => e.ProductoElaborado)         
                .WithMany(d => d.PlatoProductoElaborado)         
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);          

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductoElaboradoProducto>()           
               .HasOne<Producto>(e => e.Producto)           
               .WithMany(d => d.ProductoElaboradoProducto)            
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);             

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductoElaboradoProducto>()         
                .HasOne<ProductoElaborado>(e => e.ProductoElaborado)          
                .WithMany(d => d.ProductoElaboradoProducto)           
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);          
        }          
       
        public DbSet<Bebida> Bebidas { get; set; }         
        public DbSet<Plato> Platos { get; set; }                      
        public DbSet<Producto> Productos { get; set; }           
        public DbSet<ProductoElaborado> ProductosElaborados { get; set; }          

        public DbSet<PlatoProducto> PlatosProductos { get; set; }          
        public DbSet<PlatoProductoElaborado> PlatosProductosElaborados { get; set; }                    
        public DbSet<ProductoElaboradoProducto> ElaboradosProductosProductos { get; set; }          
        
        public DbSet<Unidad> Unidades { get; set; }           
        public DbSet<VentasBebida> VentasBebidas { get; set; }         
        public DbSet<VentasPlato> VentasPlatos { get; set; }          
    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: Ya la he traducido. gracias.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu duda, ya modelaste tu bd en entityframework?

Comment: si ya. voy actualizo la pregunta con mis modelos y mi DBContext. el tema es que cuando voy a ejecutar las migraciones obtengo este error: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProductosProductosElaborados_ProductosElaborados_ProductoElaboradoId' on table 'ProductosProductosElaborados' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: El tema esta en que como muestra el diagrama existe una relacion circular en el diseño de la base de datos. de manera que entity necesita modificar ciertas cosas del modelo para poder manejar este problema. En realidad o que necesito es que me indiquen la mejor practica para manejar esta situacion

Comment: Hace mucho que no diseño un esquema relacional con Entity Framework. Pero creo recordar que si haces referencia a los `Id` con el atributo `ForeignKey` y después añades la *property* del objeto, EF no hará búsquedas en profundidad por defecto, sólo con las extensiones `Include` y `ThenInclude` de `IQueryable<>`. En relaciones *{N:M}* EF crea automáticamente las tablas de relación. Deberías investigar un poco sobre lo de poner la `ForeignKey` en la `Id` y no en la *property* de tipo. Quizás te ayude.

Comment: thanks. lo reviso.